# Bypass activity output to activity in switch case

Tags: elsa-workflows

I like the idea of activity inputs and outputs and prefer them over setting values in the workflow context. However I am now stuck with this approach when using switch cases. My workflow looks like this:

```
builder
  .ReceiveHttpPostRequest<ImportProducts>("/import")
  .Then<ExtractHttpRequestBodyActivity>()
  .Then<GetShopDataActivity>()
  .Switch(cases => cases
    .Add(
      context => context.GetInput<ShopData>()!.ShopType == "ShopType1",
      @case => @case
        .Then<GetShopType1ProductsActivity>()
        .Then<FilterShopType1ProductsActivity>()
        .Then<ConvertShopType1ProductsActivity>()))
  .Then<DebugActivity>();
```

Without the switch case the input of `GetShopType1ProductsActivity` is the output of `GetShopDataActivity`, but using switch case the input is `null`.

Is there a way to bypass the output to the first activity of the case?

**Edit:** I'm using Elsa 2.0.0-preview7.1545

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to bypass Elsa form sending activity output automatically to another activity as input.

That being said, it is **up to you whether or not you use output/input**.

What you can do is this:

1. Specify a *name* for `GetShopDataActivity` (using `.WithName`). E.g. `"GetShopDataActivity1"`
2. Use the output of `GetShopDataActivity` **Directly** as input for `GetShopType1ProductsActivity`.

To use output from a named activity, use the following code:

```cs
context.GetOutputFrom<ShopData>("GetShopDataActivity1");
```

An alternative approach is to store the output from `GetShopDataActivity` in a variable, then you can use that variable from other activities.

Tip: when developing custom activities, try to expose their inputs. For example, if the `GetShopType1ProductsActivity` needs the output from `GetShopDataActivity`, instead of reading input directly from the activity context within that activity, consider exposing the necessary data using an "input" property, like so:

```cs
[ActivityInput] public ShopData ShopData { get; set; }
```

Then you can update your workflow as follows:

```cs
builder
  .ReceiveHttpPostRequest<ImportProducts>("/import")
  .Then<ExtractHttpRequestBodyActivity>()
  .Then<GetShopDataActivity>().WithName("GetShopDataActivity1")
  .Switch(cases => cases
    .Add(
      context => context.GetInput<ShopData>()!.ShopType == "ShopType1",
      @case => @case
        .Then<GetShopType1ProductsActivity>(a => a.Set(x => x.ShopData, context => context.GetOutputFrom<ShopData>(""GetShopDataActivity1)))
        .Then<FilterShopType1ProductsActivity>()
        .Then<ConvertShopType1ProductsActivity>()))
  .Then<DebugActivity>();
```

This could be cleaned up a bit by adding a couple of extension methods on your `GetShopType1ProductsActivity` class (more specifically, on `ISetupActivity<GetShopType1ProductsActivity>` called e.g. `WithShopData`.

Additionally, if you need the output from `GetShopDataActivity` in multiple places (like you do already in at least two places), consider creating a an extension method that provides this information.

For example:

```cs
public static class ShoppingWorkflowExtensions
{
   public static ShopData GetShopData(this ActivityExecutionContext context) => context => context.GetOutputFrom<ShopData>(""GetShopDataActivity1)!; 
}
```

You could then update your workflow like this:

```cs
builder
  .ReceiveHttpPostRequest<ImportProducts>("/import")
  .Then<ExtractHttpRequestBodyActivity>()
  .Then<GetShopDataActivity>().WithName("GetShopDataActivity1")
  .Switch(cases => cases
    .Add(
      context => context.GetShopData().ShopType == "ShopType1",
      @case => @case
        .Then<GetShopType1ProductsActivity>(x => x.WithShopData(context => context.GetShopData()))
        .Then<FilterShopType1ProductsActivity>()
        .Then<ConvertShopType1ProductsActivity>()))
  .Then<DebugActivity>();
```

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed and helpful answer.